# Update query showing successful but it is not updating the data in table

Tags: php, mysql

My following query showing "Employee record updated Successfully" but it is not updating in the table what is wrong in my code

```
{
$eid=intval($_GET['uin']);
$uin=$_POST['uin'];
$fname=$_POST['firstName'];
$lname=$_POST['lastName'];   
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$department=$_POST['department']; 
$recoffr=$_POST['recoffr']; 
$mobileno=$_POST['mobileno'];
$sql="
update tblemployees 
   set FirstName = :fname
     , LastName = :lname
     , email = :email
     , department = :department
     , recoffr = :recoffr
     , Phonenumber = :mobileno 
 where uin = :eid
";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':uin',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':fname',$fname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':lname',$lname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':department',$department,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':recoffr',$recoffr,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':mobileno',$mobileno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$msg="Employee record updated Successfully";

}
```

Comment: If the update is not successful, what would the message be? Also, could it be the information you want to update is already the same in the table? If the information is already the same, is there any action you've made in place to inform that there are no data being updated or will it still return the 'successful' message?

Comment: @tcadidot0 This is employee information if i want to modify the information it will be updated in the same table and i m not able to that

Answer (score 1):

You have the problem in the last parameter after **where** in your query. You're using **eid** parameter in your query while binding parameter you are using **uin**.

Update your this line of code.

```
$query->bindParam(':uin',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

To this:

```
$query->bindParam(':eid',$uin,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Moreover your not using **$eid** variable anywhere in your code here.

Comment: I tried that still it is not working .$eid variable which is imported from previous php page

Comment: Are you sure the ID is there in table which you are trying to update?

Comment: Eid is not there in table but uin and others are   there in table .

Comment: If you could show us your table structure, maybe we can help you.